# counting the number of non null or non zero columns in a table 

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
ID   Name   Score_1   Score_2   Score_3
1    Abcd   4         5         5
2    Bdc    8         7         0
3    dcd    0         0         3
4    cdded  0         0         0
```

I need another column in the end which can count the number of non zero columns.Result should be like this

```
ID   Name   Score_1   Score_2   Score_3 Count
1    Abcd   4         5         5        3
2    Bdc    8         7         0        2  
3    dcd    0         0         3        1 
4    cdded  0         0         0        0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select *, 
if(score_1<>0,1,0)+if(score_2<>0,1,0)+if(score_3<>0,1,0) as `count` 
from table
```

Use a select like this when you need instead of storing a calculated field.